# Play Framework validation: Redisplay input

Tags: java, error-handling, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have created an input form.  When a user submits values and it does not pass validation,  how do I get the original values from the user to show up?  I can correctly see the validation error messages stated "field is required".  It forwards back to the input form and shows validation errors, but it does not save the values entered by the user.

The Model

```
@Entity
public class Question extends BaseModel {

    @Required
    @MaxSize(100)
    public String title;
    @Required
    @MaxSize(5000)
    public String txt;
}
```

The Controller

```
public class Questions extends Controller {

    public static void ask() {
        Question question = new Question();
        render(question);
    }

    public static void addQuestion(Question question) {
        // save question
        if (!question.validateAndSave()) {
            params.flash();
            Validation.keep();
            ask();            
        }
        Application.index();
   }
}
```

The view

```
#{form @exchange.Questions.addQuestion()}

  <label class="control-label" for="question.title">Question Title</label>
  <input type="text" class="input-large" name="question.title" value="${question.title}" />
  #{if errors.forKey('question.title')}<span class="alert-error"> #{error 'question.title'/}</span> #{/if}

  <label class="control-label" for="question.txt">Details</label>
  <textarea class="input-xxlarge span7" rows="6" name="question.txt">${question.txt}</textarea>
  #{if errors.forKey('question.txt')}<br/><span class="alert-error"> #{error 'question.txt'/}</span> #{/if}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ask Question</button> 

#{/form}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Params.flash` this adds the values you submitted in the form into the flash cookie. So, in your view, you access the values by doing something like the following

Pay particular attention to where flash is used to get the value of the form field.

```
#{ifErrors}
   <h1>Oops...</h1>
#{/ifErrors}

#{form @Application.hello()}
   <div>
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="${flash.name}" />
      <span class="error">#{error 'name' /}</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      Age: <input type="text" name="age" value="${flash.age}" /> 
      <span class="error">#{error 'age' /}</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Say hello" /> 
   </div>
#{/form}
```

Comment: I had to end up doing `${flash['question.title']}` and `${flash['question.txt']}`.  Then the original inputs showed up.